# How to fix UV's

Tags: uv, topology, retopology

Ive finished making these buildings. Now I want to UV unwrap and project the buildings to transfer to a different project. The problem is my UVs. Ive tried merging by distance and I still have bad UV's. Any Ideas? I cant move or scale the faces because it will change the look.

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: hello what do you mean by fix the UVs? If the result is the one you want, why would you change the UVs?

Comment: Search for anvil tutorial (I think modern version is chair tutorial), it teaches how to UV unwrap an object. It seems that you're missing some seams.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, I may have caused by using the wrong terms I'm a beginner still. I want to unwrap and bake these buildings to bring to a different blender project. In my UV editor, it tells me something is wrong. What should I do? Ive been researching for solutions but can't find any I've tried merging faces by distance and it hasn't helped @moonboots

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady Thanks for the reply I will check it out wish me luck!

Comment: "it tells me something is wrong" Do you have an error message? What is it? You should start by that.

Comment: Okay following the standard process. I made a new material then I smart UV projected my building on this. The first problem I noticed is my "windows" looks different now. The second problem I have is overlapping vertice. Any advice? @L0Lock

Comment: So no error message anymore? Also, your model look like they are already textured, why do you want to change de UVs?

Comment: Yeah please ignore the error message for now. I reverted to an older version of my file and have tried to begin this process again. Maybe I am communicating my problem the wrong way. I want to bring these buildings to a different project. So the first thing to do is unwrap then bake right? If this is correct, how do I fix  the problem of my windows looking different after smart UV projecting the buildings @L0Lock

Comment: How are your textures mapped in your screenshot? If it's already using UVs, then you don't need to unwrap UVs again.

Answer (score 0):

Select the sharp edges at the corner of buildings and mark those edges as seem. They should show a red tint. After you did all the necessary cuts, you can unwrap your model and you would have one "simplified" face for each side of the building in your UV.